# How is it possible to call [here-api] in a wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, here-api

I've included JavaScript and HTML codes in a code snippet plugin, but I do not know how to render the map in a Wordpress post?

This is the source code I would like to embed: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/showing-traffic-information

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Your "source code" link is actually a documentation link.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I am not able to do this alone, so I wuld be grateful if anyone could help. Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. You should post some code of your work and present some sort of effort on your part. No one is gonna write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

check shortcode API for more details 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

```
function api_func( $atts ){
    ob_start(); 
    ?>
         //HTML + jS code here
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'here-api', 'api_func' );
```